# appengine-maven-plugin. JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have described the situation that I am in at this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-plugins-core/issues/828.

I would like to deploy my Spring Boot app to Google Cloud App Engine with the appengine-maven-plugin (v2.2.0) from my Windows 8.1 64-bit computer.

**Actual situation:**

Please, have a look at the following part of the stack trace:

> Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
>   at line 2 column 1 path $
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java:939)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java:892)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java:841)
>           at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.serialization.CloudSdkComponent.fromJsonList
>   (CloudSdkComponent.java:67)
>           at com.google.cloud.tools.managedcloudsdk.ManagedCloudSdk.isUpToDate
>   (ManagedCloudSdk.java:153)

The problem is obvious: the [value of the result variable](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-plugins-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/managedcloudsdk/ManagedCloudSdk.java#L152) produced in 152nd line of ManagedCloudSdk class is not in json format.

I executed the following command in my machine with Command Prompt:

> gcloud components list --format=json --filter=state.name:Update Available

It resulted in an error because of the space character between the "Update" and the "Available":

> ERROR: (gcloud.components.list) unrecognized arguments: Available

So, I think this error message is the one that is the value of the result variable. And as it does not have the json format, it throws an exception.

**Expected situation:**

I tried the following command:

> gcloud components list --format=json --filter=state.name:"Update Available"

And it is working great, and produces an empty array as a result.
So, I am wondering what would be the result if updateAvailableCommand variable was created like this:

```
`    List<String> updateAvailableCommand = Arrays.asList(getGcloudPath().toString(),"components","list","--format=json","--filter=state.name:\"Update Available\"");    `
```

What do you think? Or do you have a better idea?

Thank you for your help and time in advance!

Best regards,
László

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu OS with VirtualBox, and it worked.